Difficult on doing simple Bevel (Bevel modifier) + Subdivision Modificer | Hardsurface Modelling
I got to 3D model a simple box product, but I'm stuck on doing the corner bevel.

I almost got the result I was expecting, except for this normal issue there, as you can see. I tried to edit the Shade Smooth Angle, tried Normal Edit, but couldn't get it.

Then I tought, maybe I should combine with a Subdivision modifier. So, I got this result:

As you guys can see, I'm stuck in a simple bevelling operation. I can't get a satisfying result.
When using only the Bevel Modifier, if I uncheck "Loop Slide" then I get a nice result on some corners and a poor result on others:

Do you guys have any tip/trick to share?

Have you checked for duplicate vertices and/or inverted face normals? Because it looks as if the mesh is messed up there.

@GordonBrinkmann, yes. I tried to merge vertices by distance and also tried to Recalculate Normals in the whole base mesh.

@GordonBrinkmann for Jesus sake. I tried to recalculate normals to Inside and it fixed the issue with the bevel modifier.

But still, I don't understand why I get that weird result when using the bevel modifier plus a Subdivision modifier.

But "Inside" would usually mean the face normals are now pointing inward... which can bring problems with materials later. I actually believe you just cured the symptoms, but not the cause. How did you smooth the object, with Shade Smooth or Shade Smooth by Angle? And why are the bottom edges marked as crease when you have no Subdivision Surface modifier on the object in the screenshot? Because it doesn't do anything for the Bevel modifier. And is there a specific reason for the central horizontal edge? Does the bevel reach all the way down to it?

I used these creased marks on the bottom edges when trying to combine the Bevel Modifier and the Subdivision Modifier. So, now, after recalculating the normals to inside, I get a nicer result both using Shade Smooth and Shade Smooth by Angle

Now, if I apply the bevel modifier and Recalculate Normals with "Inside" unchecked, I get the normals in the right direction (pointing to outside) and the correct shading.

Well, seems like I found something interesting.
After texting with @GordonBrinkmann above, a did the following steps.

Recalculate Normals (Inside Checked). This made the shading look correct, while using the Bevel Modifier.
But, as mentioned by @GordonBrinkmann, with the normals pointing inwards, I could face some problems with materials. Then, I have applied the Bevel modifier to the mesh.
After apply the modifier, I've recalculated the normals, so they got pointing outwards like it should be.

I believe this could be some minor bug in the Bevel Modifier. It's the only thing I can think off. I've been on trial tweeking settings for some hours, until I could find this workaround.
Apply the bevel modifier was not a problem for me, because I was going to do some destructive modelling anyway, afterwards.
